# TensorFlowを用いた物の判別について

Tags: python3, tensorflow

TensorFlowを用いた物の判別について質問です。
行いたいこと:TensorFlowで犬か猫かその他かを判別するプログラムを作る事

問題:猫でも犬でもない画像を判別させた場合に、どちらか近いものを解として出す方法しかやり方がわからない事(その他であることを出す方法がわからない)

もしTensorFlowで可能なのでしょうか。
それとも他のライブラリ(OpenCVなど)を使うべきなのでしょうか。
まだソースを書いていないため抽象的な質問になってしまいますが、どうぞよろしくお願いいたします。

Comment: tensorflowというライブラリがバズりましたが、tensorflow自体はその名の通りテンソル計算をトポロジーグラフに乗せて流すための計算用のライブラリです。設問者が求めているのは物体認識だと思いますが、object detection APIなるものがtensorflowの拡張APIとして提供されているようです。ほかにもYOLOやdarknetといったライブラリも有名です。

Comment: コメントありがとうございます。
そのようなライブラリや拡張APIがあることを知りませんでした。
調べてみるとDarknetは面白そうですね。
ありがとうございました。

Answer (score 2):

コメント欄でobject detectionについて言及されていますが、
「画像の中に映るこの部分は犬だ」ではなく
「この画像は犬の画像だ」だけで良いのならばobject detectionは必要ありません。

このような問題の場合畳み込みニューラルネットワークを使用することになり
TensorFlow上にチュートリアルが用意されています。
https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/
チュートリアルはMNISTと呼ばれる基本中の基本の画像分類問題になりますので、
犬,猫の様な複雑な画像の場合は精度は良くならないかと思います、
出来合いのモデルも用意されていますのでチュートリアルで理解を得たら以下を参照してみてください。
https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/images/image_recognition

> 問題:猫でも犬でもない画像を判別させた場合に、どちらか近いものを解として出す方法しかやり方がわからない事(その他であることを出す方法がわからない)

に関しましては、学習の時点で猫でも犬でもない画像についても学習させ、「その他」としてラベリングすれば良いかと思います。

Comment: ご回答ありがとうございます。
犬のみがズームアップで映る画像のみを対象とはしていないので、できれば画像中の犬を認識させたいと思っています。
まだ知識が乏しいので、チュートリアルで簡単なところから勉強していこうと思います。
ありがとうございました。